# Emulator sdcard size limitations

Tags: android, memory, emulation

It sounds excessive, but I actually need to load a file of size 1,595,514,880 bytes onto my Google Pixel emulator sdcard.  Via Android Studio, I have upped my sdcard memory well past 2GB which would seem to be enough space.  However, when I start up the emulated phone and try:

adb push bigfile.tar /sdcard

it only copies about 700MB and then it says no more space left on device.  I know I'm missing something here but not sure what just yet.

TIA for any tips.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Does this work when you try it on hardware? It is possible that this is some limitation of `adb push` more than of the emulator.

Comment: Unfortunately - don't have hardware to test on just yet so am starting with the emulator.  (note-I have cross-compiled the relevant code to run on x86_64 processor, which matches the Google Pixel 3, thus that is my emulator, built with Android Studio.)

Comment: OK - solved things by upping the internal storage to 5Gb in the emulator.